# Foreign key in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table :

```
PROFESSOR(pid, pname)
```

and another table:

```
EXAM(examid, professorID, assistantID , examinerID, subject);
```

I want to reference `professorID,assistantID and examinerID` to `pid`. A professor can be an assistant in an exam and be examiner and also the subject belongs to a professor so professors , assistants and examiners in `EXAM` table are selected from professors in `PROFESSOR` table.

I think the schema I have designed is wrong , is it?  If its wrong how tho change it so that I can meet the condition I explained above.

Can you help please?

Comment: It's hard to tell what is being asked here. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Why are you posting pseudo code - when you could paste the actual mysql create statements? What do you mean by "i want to refrence professorID,assistantID and examinerID to pid"

Comment: @AdrianCornish I think what his trying to say is that the pid is inserted on those columns so that the professor could become a professor(professorID), assistant(assitantID) or examiner(examinerID) that's how I get it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the schema can be redesigned. You can have three tables:-

Professor(pid, pname, pAddr);

Exam(examId, subjectId, ...,..,assistantId,ExaminerId); (assistantId and ExaminerId referencing pId)

Subject(subjectId, desc, course, professorId); (professorId referencing pId)

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is wrong.

You should define three tables. Professor,Exam and subject.

For assistant and examiner you should define a column in professor table 'role'. Role column will define whether professor is professor, examiner or assistant. Professor table foreign key will go in both of the other tables. i.e. subject and exam.

I think it will help you a lot for making your tables.

Comment: I agree on creating a separate table for the subject and use the pid on the 2 other columns but I don't think he still needs to add a new column role because the column on the exam table is already enough and they are all professor so it's only in the exams that they become an examiner or assistant not sure why you really like to add the role column on the professor table, but would also like to hear your side too about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the schema is enough already base on the relationship that he needs ("A professor can be an assistant in an exam and be examiner"). He could then directly use the pid on the columns professorID, assistanID and examinerID, but however the subject should be a separate table by then instead but somehow not sure of the other details that you need for the professor table there would be more details on the actual implementation for this but anyway the important thing is that only a few tweek and you'll have a good relationship on the go. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can:

```
SELECT
       `exam`.`examID`
    , COALESCE(`professor`.`pName`,'') AS ProfessorName
    , COALESCE(`professor_2`.`pName`,'') AS AssistantName
    ,  COALESCE(`professor_1`.`pName`, '') AS ExaminerName
    , `exam`.`iSubject`
FROM
    `sampledb`.`exam`
    LEFT JOIN `sampledb`.`professor` 
        ON (`exam`.`professorID` = `professor`.`pID`)
    LEFT JOIN `sampledb`.`professor` AS `professor_1`
        ON (`exam`.`assistantID` = `professor_1`.`pID`)
    LEFT JOIN `sampledb`.`professor` AS `professor_2`
        ON (`exam`.`examinerID` = `professor_2`.`pID`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I wanted assistantID, professorID and examinerID to refrence PID. I was using Navicat to design tables visually and it was not working properly. I tested the same thing in sqlserver and mysql (using workbench) and bingo it worked .

```
CREATE TABLE `exam` (
  `examID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assistantID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `examinerID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`examID`),
  KEY `professor` (`pID`),
  KEY `assistant` (`assistantID`),
  KEY `examiner` (`examinerID`),
  CONSTRAINT `assistant` FOREIGN KEY (`assistantID`) REFERENCES `professor` (`pid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `examiner` FOREIGN KEY (`examinerID`) REFERENCES `professor` (`pid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `professor` FOREIGN KEY (`pID`) REFERENCES `professor` (`pid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

for now I just omitted subject because it needs a better schema design.